# a casa toda fica às escuras ou fica escuras

Tags: português-brasileiro

Quando o luz se apaga

> a casa toda fica às escuras.

ou

> a casa toda fica escuras.

No texto foi com **às**. Mas por que precisa **às**? O segundo frase tem outro significado?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O termo *às escuras* é uma *locução adverbial de modo*. O advérbio, na língua portuguesa, serve para modificar um adjetivo, outro advérbio ou um verbo (que é o caso do exemplo). Ou seja, a locução adverbial *às escuras* serve para indicar o modo que a casa ficou (sem luz, na escuridão).

> A casa toda fica às escuras. = Sem luz

**Atenção!**

O termo *às escuras* também pode indicar algo que foi feito de forma inconsciente ou sem saber como ou por onde prosseguir.

> A mulher foi ao encontro dele às escuras
>   A mulher foi ao encontro dele às cegas

Na segunda frase, há um erro de concordância, pois *escuras* deve concordar com o sujeito *casa*, que está no singular. Entretanto o significado é semelhante ao da primeira frase.

> A casa toda fica escura.

[Fonte](https://github.com/valdeir2000/pt-br/blob/master/answers/6289.md)